# How to detect self-intersections in a spatial path in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, curve

Let's say I have a path in a multidimensional space, given by an array of points along the path. E.g.

```
p[0] = [  0,  0,  0,   0,...]
p[1] = [  0,  0,  0,0.01,...]
```

etc.

What's an efficient algorithm for detecting if the path has any self-intersections?
It's entirely possible that the path intersects at a point in between the points I have stored.

For example, in 2D :

```
p[0] = [  0,   0]
p[1] = [  1,   0]
p[2] = [  1,   1]
p[3] = [0.5,-0.5]
```

This path doesn't have any identical points, but has a self-intersection .

Edit:

I'm currently testing if any points fall within cylinders created at each pair of points.

Here's the code I've been playing around with:

```
import numpy as np

def pairs(l):
    for i in range(0,len(l),2):
        yield (i,l[i:i+2])

def in_cyl(h0,h1,tol,p):
    # efficient cylinder test from https://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Point-In-Cylinder_Test.shtml
    l = np.linalg.norm(h0-h1)
    dx = h1-h0
    for point in p:
        pdx = point-h0
        dot = np.dot(pdx,dx)
        if dot < 0 or dot > l**2:
            # outside end caps
            continue
        else:
            # point lies within end caps. Find dist from point to cyl axis
            dsq = np.dot(pdx,pdx) - dot**2/l**2
            if (dsq > tol**2):
                # outside cyl
                continue
            else:
                # inside cyl
                return True
    return False

def self_intersect(p,tol):
    for i,(h0,h1) in pairs(p):
        if in_cyl(h0,h1,tol,np.vstack([p[:i],p[i+2:]])):
            return True
    return False

# 50-dimensional test. Intersections should be very rare
dim = 50
test_points = np.random.randn(2500,(50))
print(self_intersect(test_points,0.1))
```

On my machine, this is fairly slow.

```
%timeit self_intersect(np.random.randn(2000,(10)),0.1)
10 s ± 94.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: As soon as you go to dimension 3 or above you are going to have to consider numerical precision...

Comment: You can limit the search to pairs of pairs of adjacent points (i.e. (15-16) and (58,59)) that are co-planar (that's where numerical precision might be an issue). Then it's pretty straight forward to check if these pairs intersect.

Comment: Just one? There are dozens. You're going to have to be a lot more specific about what your use case is, exactly how many dimensions you're talking, and what you've already tried that wasn't efficient enough. Without any of that, this question is _way_ too broad.

Comment: The path can be in any dimension from 2-150. I'm evaluating a function of the path that isn't single-valued, so if I avoid self-intersections it will appear single-valued. Ideally I'd be able to set a tolerance for intersections in > 2 dimensions.

Comment: I added the code I've been trying. It's O(N^2), and slow in the common case (no intersection).

Comment: I'm still going to have to ask you what you're actually doing, first. Because self-intersections of a zero-thickness path in 3d are near impossible to achieve in data that hasn't been heavily discretised, and "paths" in more dimensions start to make very little sense (especially as you can't visualize them), you're going to have to explain what you're trying to achieve by testing for self-interesection. What thing are you trying to do that you thought "I can do this with an intersection test" for? (Because there might be better ways to do that thing)

Comment: I'm running a physics simulation. The dimensions here are values of various scalar fields, and the path is the path the fields follow on their equation of motion. I'm constructing the potential function for the equation of motion in a weird way that doesn't guarantee it to be single-valued. Physically of course, it should be single-valued. The idea with testing for self intersections is that it's more or less the equivalent of a vertical line test.

Answer (score 2):

Self-intersection search can be implemented via [BVH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) traverse with complexity of O(log(n)) + O(n*log(n)) to build the tree (usually BVH is built once and used many times for different purposes).

For this case traverse is quite simple, let me show example for binary BVH:

1. First we define task - two nodes of BVH that intersects
2. Start with task(root node, root node)
3. If `task.nodeA` = `task.nodeB`:

   - add `Task(task.nodeA.left,task.nodeA.left)`
   - add `Task(task.nodeA.right,task.nodeA.right)`
   - add `Task(task.nodeA.left,task.nodeA.right)`
4. Otherwise if `task.nodeA` intersects `task.nodeB`:

   - if `task.nodeA` and `task.nodeB` are leaves - check intersection (be careful with lines that share point, they should not be counted)
   - otherwise split the node with less volume (if it is not leaf, then split other one) and add `Task(task.smallNode,task.splitedNode.left)` and `Task(task.smallNode,task.splitedNode.right)`

You can find c++ implementation for 2d polyline in opensource library [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib) (it uses AABB tree BVH structure inside). It also has python modules where you can run following code:

```py
from meshlib import mrmeshpy
from meshlib import mrmeshnumpy
import numpy as np

# mrmeshpy uses float32 for vertex coordinates
# however, you could also use float64
points = np.ndarray(shape=(4,2), dtype=np.float32, buffer=np.array([[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.5,-0.5]], dtype=np.float32))

# create polyline structure from numpy points array
polyline = mrmeshnumpy.polyline2FromPoints(points)

# find indices of self-intersecting polyline edges
selfInters = mrmeshpy.findSelfCollidingEdges(polyline)
assert (selfInters.size() == 1)

# get line segments of that edges
segm1 = polyline.edgeSegment(mrmeshpy.EdgeId(selfInters[0].aUndirEdge))
segm2 = polyline.edgeSegment(mrmeshpy.EdgeId(selfInters[0].bUndirEdge))

# find coordinates of intersection
inter = mrmeshpy.intersection(segm1,segm2) # inter == [0.666667,0.0]
assert (abs(inter.x - 2.0/3.0) < 0.001 and inter.y == 0)
```